# On-screen dimensions of a UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uinavigationbar, bounds

I have a view controller containing a status bar and a navigation controller on top and under these a UIScrollView that fill up the remaining space. The ScrollView displays an image. Is it possible to read the on-screen dimensions of the ScrollView without any hard-coded pixel values?

For the UIScrollView both `frame` and `bounds` return the size of the entire screen (320,480).

Answer (score 3):

I am using this code to determine scrollView scrolled to the bottom end... modify it as you need.

```
if (scrollView.contentOffset.y == (scrollView.contentSize.height) - (scrollView.frame.size.height)){
            //Reached at botton
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if this code works even if the scrollView does not occupy the entire screen?

Answer (score 0):

```
contentSize - (contentSize - contentOffset)
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that contentSize returns the size of the image inside the ScrollView. I am trying to obtain (320,480-x) where x is height of status bar, navigation bar and a possible in-call status bar.

Comment: Ok, well your original question asked about finding the "on-screen dimensions of the ScrollView", not finding the height of those three components together.  However, fortunately, those components are well known sizes.  Why can't you just #define those sizes and use math to figure out what to display when you need to?

Comment: If possible, I would like to avoid hard coded pixel values since these might change. It should be possible to read the size of the scrollview programatically. The scrollview is already rendered on-screen.